# Ошибка при установке библиотеки pyautogui

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

Пытался установить библиотеку и у меня вылезла ошибка:

```
C:\Program Files\Python310\Scripts>pip.exe install pyautogui
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pyautogui
  Downloading PyAutoGUI-0.9.53.tar.gz (59 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 59 kB 426 kB/s
Collecting pymsgbox
  Downloading PyMsgBox-1.0.9.tar.gz (18 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe' 'C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\3C5C~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpul5854sq'
         cwd: C:\Users\Вова\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qj8ynysb\pymsgbox_876aa6ed51e146a38c5c7c4021fc2452
    Complete output (14 lines):
    Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
    SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 0: invalid continuation byte (sitecustomize.py, line 21)
    running dist_info
    creating C:\Users\Вова\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-h9lzggok\PyMsgBox.egg-info
    writing C:\Users\Вова\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-h9lzggok\PyMsgBox.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to C:\Users\Вова\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-h9lzggok\PyMsgBox.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to C:\Users\Вова\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-h9lzggok\PyMsgBox.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Вова\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-h9lzggok\PyMsgBox.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest file 'C:\Users\Вова\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-h9lzggok\PyMsgBox.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching '*.py' under directory 'pymsgbox'
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Вова\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-h9lzggok\PyMsgBox.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    creating 'C:\Users\Вова\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-h9lzggok\PyMsgBox.dist-info'
    error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
    ----------------------------------------
```

Как исправить?

Comment: Попробуйте в консоли написать `import pyautogui`. Что выдало?

Comment: попробуй это, а потом устанавливай pyautogui
```
pip install wheel
```